# Application.Current.properties is broken in latest xamarin forms release?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Since I've updated my xamarin installation to xamarin 4, saving local properties is not working across sessions on iOS.

so if I have 
    Application.Current.Properties.Add("key", value);
    Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();

It's not saving anything when the app is closed & restarted. 
Any pointers?

Comment: any news regarding this? I have exactly the same issue, but for Android

Comment: hi. I have the same issue. is there already a bug report?

Comment: As I suggested in my answer below, the current implementation only supports simple properties, for complex one suggest serialise & save as json string.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed by not saving the complex objects as it is, but serializing them to string using JsonConvert & then storing the string instead. 
This works all the time.

When you want to retrieve the object back again, just deserialize the string to the object type.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be a bug in Xamarin Forms 2, revert back to the latest v1 to get it working again.

See http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56461/persisting-data-locally-device-cache#latest

You should **NOT** use Xamarin Forms 2 yet, it is not production ready yet and should be considered alpha, don't believe Xamarins marketing.

Comment: Not sure why I would get downvoted for this, if you have a serious project and you are believing marketing you won't be happy with Xamarin Forms v2. Just check Xamarin Forms forum or Bugzilla and you will see a lot of problems which are sometimes so bad that you are not even able to use on of their tutorials.

Comment: Don't know who downvoted but it's may be due to the fact that XF 2.0 is now stable as per xamarin & is out of alpha.

Comment: I just downvoted because your answer simply isn't relevant. It's now a year + after your comment and the issue is still happening.

Comment: Pretty much because because Xamarin Forms is still not something you should use. Which is very relevant.